# How to make a web service in java that can be called by multiple users

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

I have a simple Web service in Java and Weblogic. In this web service, I have a method which receive some data, call another webservice, write in DB and then answer with result.

If I try it with only one call it works fine, but, if I've tried with Soap UI, creating a TestCase, where you can call the web service in multiple threads, sometimes, it works ok, but sometimes, when there are a call in the middle of another, the result is not correct.

The problem is that when I call web service method I init some variables I have to analyze and save in DB, so, if a call is interrupted, these variables are updated and when the first call finish, the result is not correct (they are with init values).

If I put  synchronized in web service method it works, but I think it's not the best way to do it, because I want to allow multiple users at the same time.

What's is the best way to do this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Which web services framework are you using? is it pure JEE? (ie. pure Servlets, Spring...)

Comment: Don't keep any state in the class that handles the webservice calls (regardless of the technology, keep everything method-local) and pool the database connection.

Comment: I'm using Java JDK 1.6 and it's only java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to kolossus comment, I've solved it removing global variables and creating only local variables, so each call will create a new variable and not overwrite common variables.

Answer (score 0):

when you start writing client specific applications, you're required to keep a data for client state in your DB. 
So, when each client accesses your web server with their cookie/session, you can get the client-id (encrypted in side cookie/session) and evaluate server-side parameters based on values of client in DB.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it isn't what I'm looking for. I don't have a client state, I want that each call doesn't overwrite variables from another call